# Bloc stream how does it get populated

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have the following home page within my app:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final CategoriesBloc _categoriesBloc = BlocProvider.of<CategoriesBloc>(context);

return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('E-Commerce'),
      centerTitle: true,
      actions: <Widget>[CartButton()],
    ),
    body: StreamBuilder(
      stream: _categoriesBloc.outCategories,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Category>> categories) {
        if (categories.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: categories.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                  title: Text(categories.data[index].name,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0)),
                  onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => BlocProvider<ProductsBloc>(
                            child: SelectedCategoryPage(),
                            bloc: ProductsBloc(categories.data[index]),
                          ))));
            },
          );
        }
        return SizedBox();
      },
    ));
}}
```

Which utilizes the categories bloc:

```
class CategoriesBloc implements BlocBase {
  List<Category> _categories;

  StreamController<List<Category>> _categoriesController = 
  StreamController<List<Category>>();
  Sink<List<Category>> get _inCategories => _categoriesController.sink;
  Stream<List<Category>> get outCategories => _categoriesController.stream;

  CategoriesBloc() {
    getCategories();
  }

  void getCategories() {
    DbApi dbApi = DbApi();
    _categories = dbApi.getCategories();
    _inCategories.add(_categories);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
   _categoriesController.close();
  }
}
```

I'm currently following a Udemy course trying to learn Flutter, my question which the instructor hasn't answered is, you see the following line:

```
stream: _categoriesBloc.outCategories,
```

This returns all categories with no issue, but how does it access the data? because from the category bloc I only populate _inCategories with data? I've gone through all the code and I can't find anywhere where outCategories gets populated?

Looking for clarification into how this actually works would be great.

Comment: they are populated from `StreamController`'s sink - whenever you call `StreamController.sink.add` you see new data in `StreamController.stream`

Comment: @pskink so the stream automatically knows of the data once it's been placed in the sink?

Comment: see [Using a StreamController](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#using-a-streamcontroller)